# Como restringir o horário de manipulação de uma tabela?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Gostaria de saber um meio de criar uma `trigger` em sql-server para restringir o horário de manipulação de uma tabela entre dois horários (8:00 as 18:00) dos dias úteis.

Comment: Votei por deixar a pergunta aberta, pois a pergunta apesar de simples e parecer ampla, pode sim ser respondida e e bastante interessante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim. Abaixo um código que faz isso, extraído de [Limit user access to a certain time](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic540295-359-1.aspx).

```
CREATE TRIGGER usrLoginCheck_LogonTrigger
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'batchid'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
declare @EarlyTime datetime,
@LateTime datetime,
@todays_date varchar(25)

set @todays_date = CONVERT(varCHAR(25),GETDATE(),110)
set @EarlyTime = Convert(datetime, @todays_date + ' 07:00:00.000')
set @LateTime = Convert(datetime, @todays_date + ' 23:00:00.000')
if ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'batchid'
and getdate() between @EarlyTime and @LateTime 
ROLLBACK;
END
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Seria possível explicar um pouco do código?